# How make mysql start automatically ? (linux-cli only)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, autostart

How can i make mysql start every time the system boot ? I need that in a dedicated server(ubuntu distro) in which i have my blog, but every time the server goes down, on booting mysql is stopped.
Btw i can use only command line.

Comment: related https://serverfault.com/questions/232046/how-to-automatically-start-mysql-after-server-restart-centos-other-distros

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can do it by using `sysv-rc-conf`, on debian based you can install it with `sudo apt-get install sysv-rc-conf`
then you can choose what start at boot with a simple X on the name of the deamon, all via command line

[image]

Comment: Again not working..I marked X mysql in all the runleves plus S but when rebooting service mysql status says mysql stop/waiting.

Comment: Sorry but what does the numbers mean on the top row?

Comment: From Ubuntu 12.10 on, `sysv-rc-conf` is the replacement for `chkconfig` recommended below. It also lets you use commands instead of the ncurses interface, in this case: `sysv-rc-conf mysql on`.

Comment: And the equivalent for CentOS/RedHat is `ntsysv` (the title of the question suggested Linux systems)

Comment: It works like charm for me on various Ubuntu versions, but doesn't create the symlinks on Debian 7. Interestingly if I quit and restart the program it keeps the "X"-es I've marked, but the daemons don't run because the symlinks in `/etc/rcX.d/` don't get created.

Answer (score 52):

**update-rc.d** allows setting init script links on Ubuntu and Debian Linux systems to control what services are run by init when entering various runlevels. It should be able to add mysql to the list of services to run at boot:

```
sudo update-rc.d mysql defaults
```

If you later want to disable running mysql on bootup:

```
sudo update-rc.d mysql remove
```

Answer (score 25):

Run the following command to see your mysql current status:

```
/sbin/chkconfig mysqld --list
```

it will return a line such as below:

```
 mysqld             0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
```

to make mysql start every time the system boots, type the following:

```
 sudo /sbin/chkconfig mysqld on
```

Result now from '--list' is:

```
mysqld          0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

Comment: Great answer. Simple and effective.

Comment: My CentOS server always started mysqld at bootup. But since yesterday it didn't any more. But this solution helped me. Great, thanks!

Comment: Tried to apply this solution, but when system is rebooted and I check my mysql service status, it says: `MySQL is not running, but PID file exists`. I know this is an old thread but we're running out of options. By the way, `/sbin/chkconfig mysql --list` command output seems to be fair. We've tried all the answers in this page but sadly with no luck.

Comment: seems like it doesn't even try to run the script inside `/etc/init.d/`

Answer (score 7):

No answer helped. Finally `chkconfig` and `update-rc.d` did not work with MySQL on my machine.

Solution, I had a file */etc/init/mysql.override* which contained

```
manual
```

i just deleted that file

```
$ sudo rm /etc/init/mysql.override
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, so I checked how I disabled it in the first place:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/138487/how-to-keep-apache-and-mysql-from-starting-automatically

Check your /etc/init/mysql.conf to make sure you don't have start on commented out (like I did).

```
# MySQL Service

description     "MySQL Server"

author          "Mario Limonciello <superm1@ubuntu.com>"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[016]
...
```

Rebooted the machine and it works.

```
$ sudo service mysql status
mysql start/running, process 972
```

Answer (score 4):

Deleting
    /etc/init/mysql.override
did the job in my case (HostEurope VPS with Ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `chkconfig` command as per the manpage http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man8/chkconfig.8.html

Answer (score 1):

Another place to look for clues as to what is and isn't starting at boot time...

**/etc/init.d/.depend.start**  (and its buddy at shutdown time, .depend.stop)

Here's a little more info http://www.pyenet.co.nz/2-202-1-customising-system-startup-and-boot-processes/

I had 2 servers - after booting, 1 would have mysql running, the other not so much.

On the box where mysql was starting at boot time:

- chkconfig wasn't even installed
- there were zero links from any scripts in /etc/rc?.d/* back to /etc/init.d/mysql
- BUT... /etc/init.d/.depend.start contained:

  ```
  TARGETS = halt apache2 umountfs umountnfs.sh sendsigs networking umountroot reboot killprocs unattended-upgrades urandom mysql mdadm dns-clean landscape-client pppd-dns sysstat rsync sudo postfix single grub-common ondemand rc.local
  INTERACTIVE = apache2
  postfix: mysql
  single: killprocs dns-clean pppd-dns
  grub-common: apache2 unattended-upgrades postfix mysql mdadm dns-clean landscape-client pppd-dns sysstat rsync sudo
  ondemand: apache2 unattended-upgrades postfix mysql mdadm dns-clean landscape-client pppd-dns sysstat rsync sudo
  rc.local: apache2 unattended-upgrades postfix mysql mdadm dns-clean landscape-client pppd-dns sysstat rsync sudo
  ```

When I simply copied this file over to the problem server, and rebooted, mysql was up & running.

Answer (score 0):

With Debian 9, I installed MySQL today and typed "reboot" and mysqld restarted automatically. Also rebooted from my VPS dashboard, mysqld restarted automatically. In short, if you have Debian 9, there's nothing extra to do, it just works.