# How can I run puma server on boot instead of crontab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

I wonder what's the better practice to run rails server with Puma and nginx on reboot.

because my crontab doesn't work.

I want to learn how to run the server automatically in other ways

```
PATH=/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/home/userA/bin:/home/userA/.rbenv/shims:/home/userA/.rbenv/bin:/home/userA/.rbenv$
SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh


@reboot zsh -l -c 'cd /project && bundle exec puma config/puma.rb'
```

Comment: Well that depends on what system you are using. You probably want to start it up with `upstart` or `init.d`.

Comment: @henrikstroem ubuntu 14.04

Comment: A few examples how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859381/how-make-mysql-start-automatically-linux-cli-only