# MySQL Service not start automatically

Tags: php, mysql, apache, service, ubuntu-18.04

When i start my laptop i have to always manually start mySQL service. is there any way to start the service automatically?

I am using below command to start the service:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859381/how-make-mysql-start-automatically-linux-cli-only

Answer (score 0):

If your OS supports systemd please use following command

`sudo systemctl enable  mysql`

Comment: Can you explain why that should be needed?

Comment: Synchronizing state of mysql.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable mysql
Failed to enable unit: Refusing to operate on linked unit file mysql.service

Comment: @NicoHaase can you please help?

Comment: Have you tried all ways from the question that NID linked?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have tried but it's not working, I am using MariaDb.